# Compiling newer versions of FFMPEG with Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, decoding

I'm currently using the "Archive for client versions 1.3.7 to 1.5.1" version of FFMPEG found at http://bambuser.com/opensource to decode audio in Android. I would like to use a newer version (do to stability and bug fixes) but it's very difficult to compile a FFMPEG source snapshot in Android without advanced "know how". Can anyone point me to a newer FFMPEG version similar to the ones found on bambuser? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest ffmpeg version I've compiled for Android was 0.8.11 "Love". You can look at my [post](http://dmitrydzz-hobby.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-build-ffmpeg-and-use-it-in.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. I may have some follow-up questions.

Comment: Do you have instructions on how to build ffmpeg for different architectures such as armeabi-v7a or x86?